# CodeLite terminal doesn't show up in mac

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, ide, codelite

When I select codelite -> preferences -> terminal -> codelite-terminal, nothing pops up when I run my program. If i select terminal instead of codelite-terminal, it does work. I have a 11.2.3 MacBook and I'm running c++17.

Does anyone know if this is a codelite bug or if not, how to fix it and make the codelite-terminal work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a relevant issue on the repo of codelite: [Codelite-terminal not working on MacOS 11.2](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/2682).

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it looks like this codelite bug hasn't been fixed yet :/